# How to add the values inside ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to get the data using web service. Now I am trying to add the values of that using ng-change. The code looks like this.

```
 <div ng-repeat="task in tasklists">
   <div ng-repeat="subtask in task.tasks">
    <span>{{subtask.subTaskName}}</span>
    <span style="float: right; padding: none; " class="t-hrs"> {{task.hours[$index]}} Hrs</span>
    <div class="cmt"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="d-task"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="range range-positive" >
        <input type='range' id="{{task._id}}_{{subtask._id}}" ng-model="task.hours[$index]" ng-init="totalChange()" ng-change="totalChange()" min='{{min}}' max='{{max}}' step='{{0.50}}'/>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

The script looks like this.

```
$scope.totalChange = function(){
    $scope.updatedTime=0;
    for (var i=0; i < $scope.task.tasks.length; i++){
      if($scope.task.tasks[i].hours !== undefined){
        //$scope.updatedTime = $scope.updatedTime+Number($scope.tasklists[i].hours);
        $scope.updatedTime +=task.hours[$index];
      }
    }
  }
```

But I am not able to get the $scope.updatedTime value. Can anyone please help.

Comment: give `taks.hours[$index]` in html `ng-change="totalChange(taks.hours[$index])"`

Comment: @Vanojx1 Where should i

Comment: what you want get in `$scope.updatedTime`? if you always add - you get something wrong

Comment: you need just add variable like `var task = $scope.task.tasks[i]` or use it directly `$scope.updatedTime +=$scope.task.tasks[i].hours[$index];`

Comment: I think you are missunderstanding ng-repeat. The fact that you can use `task` inside ng-repeat, doesn't mean that you have a `$scope.task` property. In your case, I think you should pass the task as a parameter of `totalChange` function.

Comment: Input type range give me a slider. So, If I slide them, I need to add all the values. So that I can display total

Comment: @SanthoshAineri, can you provide sample plunkr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. This is the HTML Code

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasklists">
   <div ng-repeat="subtask in task.tasks">
    <span>{{subtask.subTaskName}}</span>
    <span style="float: right; padding: none; " class="t-hrs"> {{subtask.hourscal}} Hrs</span>
    <div class="cmt"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="d-task"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="range range-positive" >
        <input type='range' id="{{task._id}}_{{subtask._id}}" ng-model="subtask.hourscal" ng-init="totalChange()" ng-change="totalChange()" min='{{min}}' max='{{max}}' step='{{0.50}}'/>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

This is the function

```
$scope.totalChange = function(){
    $scope.updatedTime=0;
    $scope.hourscal = 0;
       for (var i=0; i < $scope.tasklists.length; i++){ 
        for(var j=0; j< $scope.tasklists[i].tasks.length; j++){
          if($scope.tasklists[i].tasks[j].hourscal !== undefined){
            $scope.updatedTime = $scope.updatedTime + Number($scope.tasklists[i].tasks[j].hourscal);
          }
        }
      }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like

```html
<input type='range' id="{{task._id}}_{{subtask._id}}" ng-model="task.hours[$index]" ng-init="totalChange(task,task.hours[$index])" ng-change="totalChange(task,task.hours[$index])" min='{{min}}' max='{{max}}' step='{{0.50}}'/>
```

```js
$scope.totalChange = function(task,hour){
    $scope.updatedTime=0;
    for (var i=0; i < task.tasks.length; i++){
        if(task.tasks[i].hours !== undefined){        
            $scope.updatedTime +=hour;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Is this correct  $scope.updatedTime +=hour;  where is this hour coming from? Is it hours?

Comment: here you add value from one input to `updatedTime` a few times, i not sure that OP want this

Comment: @SanthoshAineri hour is task.hours[$index]. It is the way you can achieve the things you are doing. But I am not sure that why you are checking task.tasks[i].hours and adding the  task.hours[$index] in updatedTime . Please provide plunkr.